# Using setFill with a variable?

Tags: java, variables, javafx-8

I'm trying to pass a variable in Java, I need help getting it to work, I've included all relevant code below, there's three .java file's i'm working with.
Here's how it's all setup and how I need it to work;

PROPERTY.java

```
public enum Property {
    BACKGROUND_COLOR("LIME");
}
```

FxUtils.java

```
public Scene createScene(Text lowerKey) {
    Rectangle2D bounds = getScreenBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(createRoot(lowerKey), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    scene.setFill(Color.LIME); //WANT TO CHANGE THIS TO A VARIABLE IN PROPERTY
    return scene;
}
```

Main.java

```
Scene scene = fxUtils.createScene(lowerKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Scene createScene(Text lowerKey, Color backgroundColor) {
    Rectangle2D bounds = getScreenBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(createRoot(lowerKey), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    scene.setFill(backgroundColor);
    return scene;
}

...

createScene(text, Color.RED);
```

Comment: I think this answer would be even more helpful if you included a brief description of what your code does and how it works.

Comment: Still need help